# How to stop "hold" trajectory in joint trajectory controller when close enough

Tags: ros, ros-noetic, joint-trajectory-controller

As soon as my robot initializes its `velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController`, the arm starts swinging back-and-forth as the controller tries to reach `0` position.

I want it to stop trying to reach the goal of the "hold" trajectory when the current position is close enough.

```
arm_velocity_controller:
  type: velocity_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  publish_rate: 50
  joints:
    - base
  constraints:
    goal_time: 5
    base:
      goal: 5
      trajectory: 5
  gains:
    base:
      p: 0.4079
      i: 0.05242
      d: 0.1964
      i_clamp: 1.0
```

I tried setting extra large tolerances (like `5`) but the only seem to affect an "active goal" of the joint trajectory controller. When there is no active goal and it's in hold mode, it simply goes on trying to reach the hold position without checking any tolerances.

I tuned the PID controller so that it can reliably reach a certain position within 6 degrees of the goal, so I just want the trajectory controller to stop sending velocity commands when we're within 6 degrees or so, even if the arm overshoots the position a second after.

How do I do this with configuration? Or do I have to write my own trajectory controller?

Comment: please add information about the JTC version/ROS distro you are using

Comment: Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @ChristophFroehlich is this enough information to get the question answered?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience with ros-control